# How could I get a crew job to get to Hawaii?

Tags: transportation, sea-travel, hawaii

I'm looking for options to get from the US mainland to Hawaii and I thought doing crew work on a boat/ship/yacht might be an option. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have any experience as crew or in commercial house keeping? And do you have any paperwork to show for that?

Comment: No I have never done crew before but I have worked in hotels and in tourism for many years.  I was thinking along the lines of volunteering for the duration of the trip on a yachts/boat but I don't know anyone personally who has done this.